# .Net object not getting posted along with the request

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

i have created a wcf-rest self hosted service or web api service with a webhttp binding and attached a certificate to it to enable https. when i excecute the below code from a console application, the request is getting recived at the service end but the parameter is empty. am I doing something wrong?? please help.

[image: screen shot of the service method]

[image: Person Model]

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("John:Doe")));
    Person person = new Person() { FirstName = "Rudri", LastName = "Test" };
    HttpContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person), System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await client.PostAsync("https://0.0.0.0:8085/WtfService/HelloWorldPostComplex", content);
    var statusCode = response.StatusCode;
    var responseMessage = response.ReasonPhrase;
    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Console.WriteLine(result);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is this a _ASP.NET Web API_ or a _WCF service_? Seems like the latter to me.

Comment: @khlr its WCF service with REST enabled.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you're facing is often related to a [`WebMessageBodyStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.web.webmessagebodystyle(v=vs.110).aspx)-problem.

Make sure that your interface defines if the message will be wrapped or bare:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IWtfService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", 
               ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
               RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
               BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    void HelloWorldPostComplex(Person person);
}
```

Additionally, please notice the `WebMessageFormat.Json` statements.
Furthermore, to see what travels the wire, it's often helpful to use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to debug the HTTP traffic.